# Using mouseover and mouseout for InfoWindow causes InfoWindow flickering and consecutive event trigger of mouseover and mouseout

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps, markerclusterer

I am using [MarkerClustererPlus](https://github.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus) library in an AngularJS project with [ngMap](https://ngmap.github.io). I attached `mouseover` and `mouseout` event to `MarkerClusterer` object. When mouse is hovered over the cluster I am displaying all individual marker's detail in single `InfoWindow` of that cluster. Whenever user's mouse is out from cluster I want to hide the `InfoWindow`. Now the functionality works partially correct. When the mouse is put on the count of cluster, the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events are being called consecutively, due to that the `InfoWindow` get visible/hide and it creates a flickering effect. Am I missing anything in my code to eliminate that flicker?

I am giving you the both examples. On is in plain JavaScript and other is in AngularJs with ngMap. Also attached the video which shows the issue I am facing.

Thanks!

ngMap + MarkerClusterPlus + InfoWindow + MouseOver + MouseOut = InfoWindow Flickering Issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <title>Dynamic ngMap demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/master/dist/markerclusterer.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    MarkerClusterer.prototype.MARKER_CLUSTER_IMAGE_PATH_ 
      = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m';  //changed image path
  </script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/testapp/scripts/markers.js"></script>
  <script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMap']);

  app.controller('mapController', function($http, $interval, NgMap) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.dynMarkers = [];
    NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
    vm.map = map;
      for (var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].position[0], markers[i].position[1]);
        vm.dynMarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker({position:latLng}));
      }
      vm.markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, vm.dynMarkers, {imagePath: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m'});
      google.maps.event.addListener(vm.markerClusterer, 'mouseover', function(cluster) {
          vm.map.showInfoWindow('bar', cluster.getCenter());
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(vm.markerClusterer, 'mouseout', function() {
          vm.map.hideInfoWindow('bar');
      });
    });
  });
  </script>
  <style>
    map, div[map] {display:block; width:600px; height:400px;}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Marker Cluster</h1>
  <hr />
  <div ng-controller="mapController as vm">
    <ng-map zoom="2" center="[43.6650000, -79.4103000]" style="display:block; width:600px; height:400px;">
    <info-window id="bar" max-width="200">
        <div ng-non-bindable>
          <div id="bodyContent">
            <p>
            <b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large
            sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the
            Northern Territory, central Australia.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </info-window>
      </ng-map>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/4Yl8avzyKEgtEYvffIM7?p=preview

https://www.useloom.com/share/0e183dee979e4accb90887ba3d9ba59a

---

Plain JavaScript + MarkerClusterPlus + InfoWindow + MouseOver + MouseOut = InfoWindow Flickering Issue

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>MarkerClustererPlus V3 Example</title>

    <style type="text/css">
      .photo {
            box-shadow : 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        }

        .photo-thumblist {
            display : inline-block;
            margin : -1px 2px;
            padding : 0;
            position : relative;
        }

        .photo-longlist {
            background-color : #f1f1f1;
            border-top : 1px solid #d1d1d1;
            border-bottom : 1px solid #d1d1d1;
            height : 75px;
            overflow : auto;
            padding : 7px 7px;
        }

        .photo-preview {
            background-color : #222222;
            height : 150px;
            width : 100%;
        }

        .photo-googlemaps {
            background-color : #222222;
            border : 1px solid #222222;
            height : 300px;
            width : 100%;
        }

        .photo-map {
            background-color : #222222;
            height : 500px;
            width : 100%;
        }

        .photo-map-overlay {
            background-color : rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
            display : none;
            margin : -501px 0 0 1px;
            height : 420px;
            overflow : auto;
            padding : 40px 50px;
            position : absolute;
            width : 100%;
        }

        .photo-map-overlayclose {
            display : none;
            margin : 0 0 0 10px;
            position : absolute;
            z-index : 100;
        }

    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/master/dist/markerclusterer.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var marker;
        var gm_map;
        var markerArray = [];
        var address = 'Sweden';
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                // gm_map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                // gm_map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
            } else {
                alert("Unable to complete the geological setting due to the following error:\n\n" + status);
            }
        });



        function initialize() {
            var marker, i;
            var clusterMarkers = [
                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.381059,13.504026),
                    map: gm_map,
                    title:"P1220214 1.JPG"
                }),

                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.338683,13.492057),
                    map: gm_map,
                    title:"P1220214 2.JPG"
                }),

                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.340715,13.49631),
                    map: gm_map,
                    title:"P1220214 3.JPG"
                }),

                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.327232,13.487384),
                    map: gm_map,
                    title:"P1220214 4.JPG"
                }),

                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.379034,13.516566),
                    map: gm_map,
                    title:"P1220214 5.JPG"
                }),

                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.328631,13.485688),
                    map: gm_map,
                    title:"P1220214 6.JPG"
                }),

                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.328657,13.485591),
                    map: gm_map,
                    title:"P1220214 7.JPG"
                }),

                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.328501,13.485782),
                    map: gm_map,
                    title:"P1220214 8.JPG"
                })
                ]

            var options_googlemaps = {
                minZoom: 4,
                zoom: 18,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.328631,13.485688),
                maxZoom: 18,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                streetViewControl: false
            }

            gm_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-maps'), options_googlemaps);


            var options_markerclusterer = {
                gridSize: 20,
                maxZoom: 18,
                zoomOnClick: false,
                imagePath:  'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
            };



            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(gm_map, clusterMarkers, options_markerclusterer);

            google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'mouseover', function(cluster) {

                var markers = cluster.getMarkers();

                var array = [];
                var num = 0;

                for(i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

                    num++;
                    array.push(markers[i].getTitle() + '<br>');
                }
                if (gm_map.getZoom() <= markerCluster.getMaxZoom()) {
                   infoWindow.setContent(markers.length + " markers<br>"+array);
                   infoWindow.setPosition(cluster.getCenter());
                   infoWindow.open(gm_map);
                }    
            });
        google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'mouseout', function() {
                                infoWindow.close();
                            });


            for(i = 0; i < clusterMarkers.length; i++) {
               var marker = clusterMarkers[i];

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker) {
                    return function() {
                   infoWindow.setContent(this.getTitle());
                   infoWindow.open(gm_map, this);
                    }
                })(marker));
            }
        }



        $(document).ready(function() {

            // INITIALIZE GOOGLE MAPS
            initialize();


            // CLOSE
            $('body').on('click', '#close-link', function() {
                $('#toggle-photolist').fadeOut();
                $('#close-overlay').fadeOut();
            });

        });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="photo-map-overlayclose" id="close-overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="noborder-link" id="close-link">Close</a>
</div>


<div class="photo-map" id="google-maps"></div>
    <center class="photo-map-overlay" id="toggle-photolist">
        <div id="view-singlephoto"></div>

        <div id="view-multiblephotos">
            <div class="color-miniheadline paddingbottom-5 paddingleft-5" style="text-align: left;">
                The following photos was found in a total of <span id="count-photos">0</span>
            </div>

            <div style="text-align: left;">
                <div id="list-photos"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2onvfwdy/89/

https://www.useloom.com/share/9927951ace714557a3e8d803c96d073f

Answer (score 3):

Use this while creating infowindow, it will create a little gap between the icon and infowindow

```
pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -5)
```